# read() system call does a copy of data instead of passing the reference

Tags: c, linux, process, ipc

The `read()` system call causes the kernel to copy the data instead of passing the buffer by reference. I was asked the reason for this in an interview. The best I could come up with were:

1. To avoid concurrent writes on the same buffer across multiple processes.
2. If the user-level process tries to access a buffer mapped to kernel virtual memory area it will result in a segfault.

As it turns out the interviewer was not entirely satisfied with either of these answers. I would greatly appreciate if anybody could elaborate on the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is specified by the caller, so the only way to get the data there is to copy them. And the API is defined the way it is for historical reasons.

Note, that your two points above are no problem for the alternative, `mmap`, which does pass the buffer by reference (and writing to it than writes to the file, so you than can't process the data in place, while many users of `read` do just that).

Comment: With `MAP_PRIVATE`, writing to the map does not modify the file.

Answer (score 3):

A zero copy implementation would mean the user level process would have to be given access to the buffers used internally by the kernel/driver for reading.  The user would have to make an explicit call to the kernel to free the buffer after they were done with it.

Depending on the type of device being read from, the buffers could be more than just an area of memory.  (For example, some devices could require the buffers to be in a specific area of memory.  Or they could only support writing to a fixed area of memory be given to them at startup.)  In this case, failure of the user program to "free" those buffers (so that the device could write more data to them) could cause the device and/or its driver to stop functioning properly, something a user program should never be able to do.

Comment: Note that e.g. recently kernels implement 'splice' support which means zero-copy paths now exist for fuse drivers

Answer (score 0):

I might have been prepared to dispute the interviewer's assertion.  The buffer in a `read()` call is supplied by the user process and therefore comes from the user address space.  It's also not guaranteed to be aligned in any particular way with respect to page frames.  That makes it tricky to do what is necessary to perform IO directly into the buffer ie. map the buffer into the device driver's address space or wire it for DMA.  However, in limited circumstances, this may be possible.

I seem to remember the BSD subsystem used by Mac OS X used to copy data between address spaces had an optimisation in this respect, although I may be completely mistaken.